# send file to another website without file upload script on receiving website with curl and php

Tags: php, curl

I already know how to upload files via post data with php.
But is it possible to upload a file to a different website with curl
NB: there is no script on the receiving website to handle file uploads
    Just send a file to the website from another website straight up.

How is that possible with php and curl ?

Comment: There has to be something to receive the file on the other end: ssh, ftp... What do you have available?

Comment: With [simple post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892617/curl-php-file-upload) or [ftp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223977/send-file-via-curl-from-form-post-in-php)

Comment: Well let them run a FTP server and you can use that, else they will have to code a "handler" on their side.

Comment: It can't be done with just PHP and curl and nothing on the receiving end, you will have to use a more direct protocol like FTP or SSH.

Comment: Ok, so i can do that with FTP but then it would require authentication  right ?

Comment: Yeah, go check https://filezilla-project.org/ for the server and check php ftp-put here http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php . You can you use cURL as well