# PHP : Best way to transfer files from server to server

Tags: php, ftp, xampp

I have a server which hosts a intranet site and files. Site Administrators need to be able to come onto the site and push selected files to other servers on the same network at the push of a button. Eventually though this feature could include servers outside the network.

What is the best way to go about sending these files (i.e plugins, libraries etc)?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `CURL` OR `AJAX`.

Comment: SCP (secure copy) over the command line.

Comment: @str Thanks that seems to do the trick. I am using the Putty equivalent. Stupid question: is it possible for that batch file that could run this enter the password for the user as well? or can it be avoided completely? Thanks again for everyone's input.

Comment: Turns out pscp has an option to add in the password when copying files. `pscp -pw password`

Answer (score 0):

You can write php script that will list the files, along with checkboxes and a form. On form submit you use get selected files and use [ftp_nb_fput](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-fput.php) function to send them to destination server using ftp. For better experience you can create javascript based file manager and send "request to send" using ajax.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do like your idea of the check boxes but I have experimented with the php ftp functions but have had no success connecting to the other server. I believe it is some kind of compatibility issue where ftp functions don't quite work with some servers. Although I could be wrong (very likely). Thank you again.

Comment: @Pod if ftp don't work you can create upload script on the server and use curl in php to upload a file. Here is question about it on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892617/curl-php-file-upload