# I receive a HTML form response from cURL request

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to connect with an external server for a job.  However, I am confused as to how to proceed.  I have the following code:

```
$username = '****';
$password = '****';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://****:9443/submitorder'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $result;
```

And when I `echo $result` now, I get a HTML Form:

[image: This is the <code>$results</code> I get back from the cURL request:]

How am I supposed to POST to that form using cURL? I need to upload a custom XML script to it, but as I understood cURL, everything was done using one request.  You connected, uploaded, and received a response all in one request.  How do I get my data into this server?

The HTML I receive back in `$result` is the following:

`<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
XML Order Envolope File: <input name="filename" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curl PHP File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892617/curl-php-file-upload)

Answer (score 1):

To upload a file using POST, use the [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option:

> **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**
>
> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation.
>
> To post a file,
>   prepend a filename with `@` and use the full path.
>
> The filetype can be
>   explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the
>   format `;type=mimetype`.
>
> This parameter can either be passed as a
>   urlencoded string like `para1=val1&para2=val2&...` or as an array with
>   the field name as key and field data as value.
>
> If value is an array,
>   the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.

**Example**

```
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('filename' => '@C:/MyFile.xml');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://yourserver/post.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Would it not be: `$data = array('filename' => '@C:/MyFile.xml');` ??

Comment: Also do I have to reference a file? Can I POST the `filename` as a string?  Surely that's all the cURL would do anyway, get the data from the local file and put it into a string

Comment: @Chud37: Yes, you were right about the data array key-value pairs.

Comment: @Chud37: I don't believe that can be done, unless you save the string to a file (temporarily) using `tempnam` or `file_put_contents`. You can `unlink` the file to delete it once you're done.

Comment: Thank you @Hippo, You have been really helpful ! I really appreciate it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38670/discussion-between-chud37-and-hippo)